How to save an untitled file before executing a task?
In Visual Studio Code I do an XSL transformation using the XSL Transform extension, which creates a file named "Untitled-1" as a result. I want to further process the resulting file with an external tool, but that tool needs an existing file (or stdin) as input. Can I save the untitled file as temporary file with a preset name in a task?
Or is there an XSLT extension that allows an output file name?

scan directory before and after and take the newly created file !

If you mean the directory where the source file resides: no changed files here.

I couldn't find a file save command that allows to specify the filename as an argument. I checked workbench.action.files.save, workbench.action.files.saveAs, and workbench.action.files.saveLocalFile. Maybe I missed one, or maybe it just doesn't exist as a feature right now. If you can't find one, consider raising a feature-request issue ticket.

If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.
